# how to do history.push location inside axios interceptor with react react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, push, router, react-router-v4, history

There is a need to push to a specific location say '/login' based on statuses inside interceptor.

Is there a way to directly push to a location?

Comment: please try to use `this.props.history.push("/login");`

Comment: @Jin what's `this.props` inside an interceptor?

Comment: I'm trying to push outside a component. inside an interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and ugly way could be.
***window.location.replace('/myUrl')***

**UPDATE**

***A WorkAround could be***

**/**RootComponent*/**

```
export const myRouter = {};
@withRouter()
Class RootComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       myRouter = this.props.router;
    }
    render() {
      return <Provider store={store}>
            <MainComponent/>
         </Provider>
    }
}
```

**/**Interceptor*/**

```
import { myRouter } from 'RootComponent';

if (status == 401) {
    myRouter.push('/myUrl');
}
```